# How can I change the link in comment form "Log in to post a comment"?

Tags: comments

Right now there is a link and I am using a plugin for a modal box and I would like to change the link in the code.

Where is the html and php file with the code located?

I have looked in my theme files, but comments.php do not contain the code I need to change.

Can I hack it via functions.php hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the link is called from within `comment_form()` (/wp-includes/comment-template.php line 1539) :

```
'must_log_in'          => '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( $post_id ) ) ) ) . '</p>',
```

and uses `wp_login_url()` (/wp-includes/general-template.php lines 224+) which uses a filter on its return:

```
 return apply_filters('login_url', $login_url, $redirect);
```

you might be able to add a filter function to functions.php of your theme, to influence the link;
example:

```
add_filter( 'link_url', 'wpse_71100_linkchanger');
function wpse_71100_linkchanger( $link ) {
  /*whatever you need to do with the link*/
  return $link;
}
```